# dynamically match textbox width with gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, gridview

I am trying to dynamicly resize a number of textboxes so that they match my gridviews tableheads width. The gridview will allways have the same number of columns but they may vary in width. As you can see on the image, the width values doesn't match at all.

The values comes from:

- black = width from code
- red = width of textbox by inspecting element (firefox)
- blue = width of tablehead by inspecting element (firefox)

[image: black = width from code, red = width of textbox, blue = width of tablehead]

Here's the script & style:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= myGridView.ClientID %> th").each(function (index) {
            $('input[type="text"]:eq(' + index + ')').css('width', $(this).width());
            $('input[type="text"]:eq(' + index + ')').css('padding', '0');
            $('input[type="text"]:eq(' + index + ')').val($(this).width());
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    input[type="text"] {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

**As requested, my ASP code**

```
<input type="text" id="id0"/><!-- Comments are needed to get rid of whitespace between text boxes
         --><input type="text" id="id1"/><!--
         --><input type="text" id="id2"/><!--
         --><input type="text" id="id3" /><!--
         --><input type="text" id="id4" /><!--
         --><input type="text" id="id5" /><!--
         --><input type="text" id="id6" />
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" 
                HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" PagerStyle-CssClass="GridPager" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridFooter" 
                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass ="GridAltItem" CssClass="Grid" ShowFooter="True" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="myDataSource" 
                OnRowUpdating="myGridView_RowUpdating">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="1" HeaderText="1" SortExpression="1" ReadOnly="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="2" HeaderText="2" SortExpression="2" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="3" HeaderText="3" SortExpression="3" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="4" HeaderText="4" SortExpression="4" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="5" HeaderText="5" SortExpression="5" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="6" HeaderText="6" SortExpression="6" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="7" HeaderText="7" SortExpression="7" />
                    <asp:commandfield showeditbutton="True" />
                    <asp:commandfield showdeletebutton="True" />
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle CssClass="GridFooter"></FooterStyle>
                <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager"></PagerStyle>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader"></HeaderStyle>
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAltItem"></AlternatingRowStyle>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this alone is sufficient

```
 input[type="text"] {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you tried that after removing jquery code? your gridview `th` and `td` have the same width right for same column (may differ for different cols)?

Comment: also try changing the selector to `$("#"+<%= myGridView.ClientID %>+" th").`

Comment: btw are you adding the textboxes inside a seperate table above the gridview??

Comment: I added the gridview code + textboxes code to my question now

Comment: just to check, can you remove the border for gridview and see if the text boxes line up?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34604/discussion-between-rps-and-litari)